# bash shellscript for loop two variables with input from two files

Tags: shell-script

bash shellscript  for loop   two variables with input from two  files

I have a  file1:

I need to compare usedmem(column5)from file2 with free memory(column4) from file1. If free memory(column4) from file1  is greater than usedmem(column5)from file2. The output should be  VM(column2) from file2 can be relocated to storage(column1) in file1. Files are sorted in descending order

```
storage,totalmem,usedmem,freemem

0843,524230,241374,282856  
0867,524230,253339,270891  
0842,524230,291427,232803  
0868,262086,48660,213426    
0849,524230,335445,188785  
0844,524230,335446,188784  
0860,524230,354981,169249  
0855,524230,354984,169246  
0862,524230,354985,169245  
0853,524230,354986,169244  
0850,524230,411733,112497  
0857,524230,411734,112496  
0841,524230,411734,112496  
0839,524230,411735,112495  
0848,524230,411736,112494  
0851,524230,411737,112493
```

file2

```
storage, vm ,rack,usedcpu,usedmem,type  
0839,x0aaa05,US1 DA12,4,78851,FA  
0839,x0aaa01,US1 DA12,5,10243,OIM  
0839,x0aaa03,US1 DA12,6,4099,OHS
```

Desired output -

```
significant memory does not exist in 0843 to relocate x0aaa06  
x0aaa05 can be relocated to 0867  
x0aaa01 can be relocated to 0842  
x0aaa03  can be relocated to 0868
```

I have been trying to use for loop to pass something like

```
for i in `cat file2|wc -l`  
do  
   j=`cat  file1|cut -d, -f4`  
   m=`cat  file2|cut -d, -f5`  
   file1_dom=`cat  file1|cut -d, -f1`  
   file2_vm=`cat  file2|cut -d, -f2`  
        if [[ `${j} -gt ${m}` ]]  
        then  
             echo ${file2_vm} can be reclocated to ${file1_dom}  
        fi  
done
```

output -  erroring out

```
-bash: 282856: command not found
```

example 2-

```
set -- $( cat file1|cut -d, -f4 )  
for i in `cat file2|cut -d, -f5`  
do  
   if [[ $1 -gt $i ]]  
   then  
       echo $1  can be relocated to $i  
   fi  
done
```

Output -

```
282856 can be relocated to 78851  
282856 can be relocated to 10243  
282856 can be relocated to 4099
```

Comment: _please_, take a look at the [editing help](https://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help), especially the first point about code block formatting. Then take some time to [edit] the formatting of your post to make the question more readable. Also, there's no need to use shorthand for words like "output" (which I suppose you mean with "o/p"). The bits are cheap enough to spell it out, and the question is more understandable without uncommon abbreviations.

Comment: Also please explain (in words) the logic applied to combine both files in order to create the output.

Comment: I need to compare usedmem(column5)from file2 with free memory(column4) from file1. If free memory(column4) from file1  is greater than usedmem(column5)from file2. The output should be  VM(column2) from file2 can be relocated to storage(column1) in file1.

Comment: formatted code as well and have rewritten bits as suggested

Comment: If I understand correctly, ALL freemem entries in file1 are greater than ALL usedmem entries in file2. So - should the output have 16 * 3 = 48 lines reporting all VMs  to be relocatable?

Comment: The first line of file1 will be compared to only first line of file2 . Second line of file1 with only second line of file2 and so on.. so the number of lines should be only the number of lines present in file2, which sums up to 3

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in `cat file2|wc -l`  
do  
   j=`cat  file1|cut -d, -f4`  
   m=`cat  file2|cut -d, -f5`  
   file1_dom=`cat  file1|cut -d, -f1`  
   file2_vm=`cat  file2|cut -d, -f2`  
        if [[ `${j} -gt ${m}` ]]  
        then  
             echo ${file2_vm} can be reclocated to ${file1_dom}  
        fi  
done
```

Several issues I see with your code fragment:

- Don't use backticks to start sub-shell, they've been deprecated for some time. Prefer the `$(cmd)` syntax.
- It's unnecessary to write `cat file2 | wc -l` for example, `wc -l file2` is shorter and more efficient. (No need to start `cat`, pipe its `stdout` to `wc`, etc.)
- You should always, always, *always* quote *all* variable substitutions unless you want them to be subject to word splitting and globbing. I'm referring to unqouted `${file1_dom}`. Also, it's unnecessary to write `${file1_dom}`, `$file1_dom` would be preferred (the ${...} syntax offers some other goodies which are unnecessary here).
- Likewise, you should always prevent common scripting errors by adding `-eu` to the interpreter line (shebang) of your scripts.
- You don't need to use `[[` for simple numerical comparisons, `[` is sufficient.
- The bug is probably in the comparison: `${j} -gt ${m}` is surrounded by backticks and hence executed in a subshell, so that the value of `j` is taken as command name. (That's where the message comes from.) You want something like `if [ "$j" -gt "$m" ]; then ...`, applying all of the rules above.

If you choose to rewrite your script in accordance with these rules, please add it to your original post, so that others can benefit from seeing that correct scripting makes difference.